# Django request.user returns 'NoneType'

Tags: django, view

I am setting up a djangos channel and I am receiving the following error when I visit Threadview at the url below. It seems that it can't query the user? The user is "dominic" and I am signed in, but the view doesn't seem to be able to request.user.. See error message referencing line 99 below.

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/messages/dominic/

**Error:**

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /home/dominic/Desktop/Projects/robobud/web/robobud/portal/views.py in get_object, line 99
Python Executable:  /home/dominic/Desktop/Projects/robobud/web/env/bin/python3
```

**Line 99 from views.py:**

```
def get_object(self):
...
obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username) #Line99
```

**Urls.py:**

```
#channels
path("messages/", InboxView.as_view()),
#url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
path('messages/<username>/', ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
```

**Views.py:**

```
class InboxView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'portal/inbox.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)


class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'portal/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = './'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user,
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False


class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects      = ThreadManager()

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return 'chat_{self.id}' #Removed f

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False


class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread      = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: You need to show your `get_or_new` manager method, and probably the Thread model as well.

Comment: Okay I added models

Comment: That method returns None if the logged-in username is the same as the username in the URL, which would trigger your error.